# How to use fix header in print screen

Tags: php, html, css, printing

I'm printing a page with the window.print command and I want the data in the header part to appear fixed on the 2nd page. However, the rest of the created table overlaps with the header div. It looks as shown in the photo. How can I prevent this?

```
<div class="header">
    <center><div class="home-container1">
        <h1 class="home-text">PACKING LIST</h1>
        <img src="logo.svg" alt="image" class="home-image" />
    </div></center>
    <div class="date">
        <b>Date: </b><?php echo date('d/m/Y'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left-box">
            <p><b>FEURST</b></p>
            <p>BVD de la Boissonnette 42110 FEURS FRANCE</p>
        </div>
        <div class="middle-box">
            <p><b>Customer: </b><?php echo $name; ?></p>
            <p><b>Customer Code:</b> <?php echo $customer_code; ?></p>
            <p><b>Billing Address: </b><?php echo $billing_address; ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="right-box">
            <p><b>Delivery Code: </b><?php echo $delivery; ?></p>
            <p><b>Delivery Address: </b><?php echo $delivery_address; ?></p>
            <p><b>Contact :</b> <?php echo $contact; ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $mail; ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $phone; ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header1">
        <figure>
            <p><b><?php echo $total_box_count ?> SEA WOODEN CRATES / unit sizes 0,80 M X 1,20 M X 0.67 M</b></p>
            <p><b>Total Net weight:</b> <?php echo  $toplam_agirlik;?> Kg</p>
            <p><b>Total gross weight:</b> <?php echo  $gros;?> Kg</p>
            <p><b>Incoterms:</b> <?php echo $incoterms; ?></p>
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tablo" >
    <table>
        <thead>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php echo $table; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

print.css code :

```
@media print {
  .header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    display: table-header-group;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
  body {
    zoom: 71%;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    print-color-adjust: exact;
  }
  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
  }
  tbody {
    display: table-row-group;
  }
  tr {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    display: table-row;
  }
  td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: left;
  }
  tr:last-child td:first-child {
    page-break-before: avoid;
  }
  .tablo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: 600px;
        page-break-inside: avoid;

        clear: both;
 page-break-before: always;
    margin-top: 600px;
  }
  .page:after {
    content: "";
    height: 600px; /* 
    page-break-after: always;
  }
  
}
```

this image is  my print screen as you see both div crashed [image]

How can I prevent this?

Comment: What is your expected result? Should the header appear on 3rd page if contents of first page are longer than one page? You said you want the header part to appear fixed on 2nd page - this is already the case but it seem to be not what you want.

Comment: Yes if you look at second page . header part and table part appear on top of each other. in normally the table must be under the header

Comment: Fixed positioned elements are supposed to repeat on _every_ page of the print output - which does not appear to be what you actually want here in the first place. Question is - what _do_ you actually want to achieve here? Give some more context.

Comment: https://ibb.co/Mk6nHBM
https://ibb.co/f0VdcsK as you see that pictures . first page norma but second page table and fix header on top of each other